# Requested client not authorized

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-app-engine, google-api, google-apps

I am trying to get google users from my domain using `google service account`.

But it throws error

```
Error:"access_denied", Description:"Requested client not authorized.", Uri:""
```

My code

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(key_path,
                         "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
           new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer("publickey.gserviceaccount.com")
           {   Scopes = scopes,
               User = "admin@domain.com"
           }.FromCertificate(certificate));

var service = new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "appname",
        });

service.Users.List().Domain = "domain.com";
Users results = service.Users.List().Execute();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you already tried? So many things can be wrong, the certificate, the installation of the certificate, the user you are using, etc...

Answer (score 1):

The service account email address needs to have access the domain.  Take the email and add it as a user just enough access that it can read should be good.

Also did you change this for posting?

```
"publickey.gserviceaccount.com"
```

A service account email  looks more like this:

```
539621478854-imkdv94bgujcom228h3ea33kmkoefhil@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

Comment: Did you give the Service account access to read the Google users from your domain?

Comment: Lets try this again.   Did you go to your domain and add the service account as a user giving it access to read this information?

Comment: I've set the edit permissions for this service account in my Developer Console. I still get an access denied error. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your service-account/API project access to your domain first.
Steps detailed in the docs here:

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account

You need to specify the correct scopes you need in step 6 of those instructions, which would be `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly` to access the list of users.

In addition for the Directory API to work you need to enable API access in the domain settings: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/prerequisites#set_up_api

Comment: All the above points you have mentioned have already been done. I still get the access denied error. Could this problem be due to the DLL I'm using - I downloaded this from Google Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.Data. Is there a later version of this DLL?

Comment: All the newest Client Library files available here, there was a new update a few days back, but I don't think that should be the issue: http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=google.apis&prerelease=true&sortOrder=relevance

Comment: Just to make sure the setup steps are correct: During setup in the Admin console you have to use the `Client ID` which looks like `randomstring.apps.googleusercontent.com`, for ServiceAccountCredential you have to use the `Email address` which looks like `randomstring@developer.gserviceaccount.com`

Comment: Yes i have verified these steps again, still i am getting this error.

Comment: Hi I have assigned certificate file path like this --string path = "d:\\5e0938f59e0d3b88508670ce1c6b82065f26fbb0-privatekey.p12";-- is this correct or not? Please verify.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get this working. Here is the code I have

```
        var grpReq = service.Groups.List();
        grpReq.Domain = "mydomain.com";
        Groups groups = grpReq.Execute();

        IList<Group> gps = groups.GroupsValue;

        var memReq=service.Members.List(groups.GroupsValue[0].Id);
        Members members = memReq.Execute();
```

I am still not sure why creating a var object and then Execute() got this to work but the earlier code didn't work.

I still have the problem of the consent screen showing up for all users. I have the following code. I think the way I get the logged in user's email is incorrect. Any ideas?

```
        string mymail = googleauth.GetUsersEmail(ExchangeCodeWithAccessAndRefreshToken().Access_Token);

        string path = "d:\\c6b82065f26fbb0-privatekey.p12";
        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(
            path,
            "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
          new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer("876131792-v824u6drpss@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
          {
              User = mymail,
              Scopes = new[] { PlusService.Scope.UserinfoEmail, PlusService.Scope.UserinfoProfile, PlusService.Scope.PlusMe }
          }.FromCertificate(certificate));


        PlusService plus = new PlusService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "myapp"
        });

        Person profile = plus.People.Get("me").Execute();
        string email = profile.Emails[0].Value;
```