# Google Admin SDK error - method not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api, google-apps, google-admin-sdk

I am trying to get users from my google domain using google service account.

But it throws error.

Error:

```
   Method not found: 'Boolean             
   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse.IsExpired(Google.Apis.Util.IClock)'.
```

Code:

```
        string path = KeyPath;
        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(
            path,
            "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
           new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer("x@developer.gserviceaccount.com")

           {
               Scopes = new[] { DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryGroupReadonly, DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryGroupMemberReadonly, DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUserReadonly },
               User = "admin@mydomain.com"
           }.FromCertificate(certificate));


        var service = new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "cavinHR",
        });

        service.Users.List().Domain = "mydomain.com";
        Users results = service.Users.List().Execute();
```

I am receiving this error on this line

```
        **Users results = service.Users.List().Execute();**
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the time on the machine that you are running.  Is it correct?

Comment: hi thanks DalmTo, now i fixed this issue. But can u help me for another issue. Please refer this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23888276/requested-client-not-authorized Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That error normally means that the clock on the machine running the script is incorrect.  Check it and try and run again.   Google Authentication is very picky when it comes to the time being correct.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, now i have fixed this, after fix this now i got another issue, please verify this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23888276/requested-client-not-authorized