# Service account authentication

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client, service-accounts

I'm trying to create calendar event via PHP for one particular user - say developement@example.com.

I've created Service Account in Google Developers Console, got ClientID, E-mail address and private key. The authentication is done with code:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
if (isset($_SESSION['service_token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['service_token']);
}
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
  'somelongstring@developer.gserviceaccount.com.',
  array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'),
  file_get_contents('p12 file'));
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}
$_SESSION['service_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
```

This type of authentication seems pretty OK. But all events are created as user with E-mail address somelongstring@developer.gserviceaccount.com instead of developement@example.com.

I've tried setting sub parameter:

```
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
....
$cred->sub = 'developement@example.com';
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
```

But this piece of code throws exception:

```
Google_Auth_Exception: Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "access_denied", "error_description" : "Requested client not authorized." }'
```

And now I'm lost. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, resolved ;-)

Problem was with developement on own domain.

As mentioned in [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23888276/requested-client-not-authorized/24016646#24016646) and in [Google SDK Guide](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account) I have to grant access for service account to **all** scopes I request access. I forgot to add read-only scope.