# Google Contacts API : Requested client not authorized

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-contacts-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I need to make a windows service which daily exports contacts from a database to my Google Contacts Account.

Since the application is a service and the account is mine, I don't want/need to use browser authentication, but I managed to set up a service account.

I'm testing it but, right now, when I request the access token I get the "Requested client not authorized" error message

First off, the configuration: I have my "destination" account, the one I want the contacts to be imported, which is info@mydomain.com

In the Developer Console, being logged as info@mydomain.com, I created new credentials -> Service Account Key as contactimporter@mydomain-123456.iam.gserviceaccount.com; I downloaded the .p12 key and enabled the Domain-wide Delegation

Then, I went in the Admin panel of the Google Apps Account, and then
Security -> Show More -> Advanced settings -> Manage API Client Access

I entered the service accont client id and "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/" as scope

[API Scope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HefJ.jpg)

Finally, the code:

```
var _uName = "info@mydomain.com";
var _pWord = "password!";           //info@mydomain.com's password
var _aSrvE = "contactimporter@mydomain-123456.iam.gserviceaccount.com";

var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Test\GoogleContactsExporter-123456789.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
           new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(_aSrvE)
           {
               Scopes = new string[] { "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds"},
               User = _uName
           }.FromCertificate(certificate));
var task = credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(new CancellationToken());
task.Wait();
```

On `task.Wait()` I get this exception:

> System.TypeInitializationException: L'inizializzatore di tipo di
>   'LibraryTest.GoogleContactsHelper' ha generato un'eccezione. --->
>   System.AggregateException: Si sono verificati uno o più errori. --->
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException:
>   **Error:"access_denied", Description:"Requested client not authorized.", Uri:""**     in
>   Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)     in
>   Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task
>   task)     in
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential.d__19.MoveNext()

I think I've done everything ok, I don't know what to check more: any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried reading this SO ticket? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23888276/requested-client-not-authorized

Comment: thanks, I've read it, but unfortunately the owner didn't found a "real" solution, he just managed to refactor the code using a structure that I don't have: PlusService has no equivalent for the Contacts API, as far as I know

Answer (score -1):

you use the old google api authorization methode. I don't know is supported in this time.
Try to use the OAuth 2.0 authorization [Google OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#installed-applications)

Hopefuly this helps.

Andreas